# Return on click back browser action

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem on my application angularjs.

I have 4 step checkout.

The second step is the signin/signup step.

If you go on the third step and you click on back button on your browser, it will redirect to the third step because you are already logged.

*Example :

Step 1 : Offers

Step 2 : Signin Signup

Step 3 : Payment
..*

If you go on signin/signup and you are already logged, it will redirect on step 3.

**So if you want to back to step 1, you can't because browser try to access to Step 2 and redirect on step 3.**

Any tips for that ?

**My controller of step 2 :**

```
...

if ($cookies.get(config.connectionCookie)) {
    $location.path('/step3');
}

...
```

Comment: Can you please add angular route code?

Comment: @PraveenMP It's works fine, it's an example, i just want to know how to return on the first step when you click on back button of browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours, I have make a little hack for this :

On my step 3, I add a variable on my rootscope :

```
$rootScope.referer = "step3";
```

And on my step 2 I have modified the controller like this :

```
if ($cookies.get(config.connectionCookie)) {
    if($rootScope.referer == "step3"){
        delete $rootScope.referer;
        $location.path('/step1');
    }else{
        $location.path('/step3');
    }
}
```

It's really simple and make the job, It's a referrer, this variable is created only on step 3 and is deleted on step 2 before redirect to step 1.

So now we are on step 1 and want to go on step 2, referrer variable is not defined so it will redirect on step 3 and referrer variable is recreated for make another back if I want.